# the trait `Future` is not implemented for `Result<std::net::TcpListener, std::io::Error>

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

I try to initialize a server in rust with async functionality using Tokio library:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // let listener=TcpListener::bind("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await.unwrap();
    let (socket,_addr)=listener.accept().await.unwrap();
}
```

This throws an error saying that:

```
 the trait `Future` is not implemented for `Result<std::net::TcpListener, std::io::Error>`
```

When I hover over `listener` its type is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
```

And you probably want to have:

```
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
```

Here is an example from [`tokio`'s docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.16.1/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html):

```
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

use std::io;

async fn process_socket<T>(socket: T) {
    // do work with socket here
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    loop {
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        process_socket(socket).await;
    }
}
```